# Plot a dataframe with different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a data frame where I need to plot X-Y axis value (Itow - X-axis , Icorr - Yaxis) and label them based on svid .

My data fame looks like this:

[image]

- I need to plot Itow on X-axis and ionoCorr on Y-axis.
- I need to check what is svDataSvId used for each iTOW and show it as a label across the plot , each unique **svDataSvId**  representing a color and as a label
- I need to create two such similar sub-plots when sourceId=1 and another when sourceId=2
- My plot should look something similar to like this. Each label (eg: 300,301 ), on the right side represent the **svDataSvId** used for each Itow

[image]

This is what i have tried , but I am not sure how I can represent the **svDataSvId** used for each **Itow** here

```
        list_id=[9,10,4,36,2,30,34,11,10]
        for i, (source_id, list,color) in enumerate([(1,list_id, "green"), (2,list_id, "red")]):
            mask = (final_df1["sourceId"] == source_id) & (final_df1["svDataSvId"] == list)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.plot(final_df1[mask]['iTOW'], final_df1[mask]['ionoCorr'], color=color, label=f"Source {source_id}")

            ax.set_ylabel("Correction")
            ax.set_xlabel("Itows")
```

Comment: It's hard to see from the plot provided -- but you need the colors to alternate according to `svDataSvId` along a single line segment?

Comment: To be suitable for StackOverflow, it is necessary to provide your data in text (or code) form, never as an image.

Comment: Maybe you can use seaborn?  `sns.lineplot(data=final_df1[mask], x='iTOW', y='ionoCorr', hue='svDataSvId', ax=ax)`.  Seaborn is a statistical visualization library build on matplotlib and pandas.  Creating similar plots in matplotlib needs much more code, which is harder to read and maintain.

Comment: @A10 , yes I need the colors to alternate according to svDataSvId along a single line segment , when source_id=0 or 1 in two different sub plots

Answer (score 0):

If you're just hoping to have multiple conditions to represent each case of `svDataSvId` as well as `source_id`, you're 99% of the way there, you'll need to update your `mask` to something like:

```py
source_id = "id_1" # or whatever
svDataSvId = 1 # or whatever

mask = (final_df1["sourceId"] == source_id) & (final_df1["svDataSvId"] = svDataSvId)

final_df.plot(x = 'iToW', 
              y = 'ionoCorr', 
              color = color, 
              label = label, 
              ax=ax)
```

Where you just need to add the additional filter to where you're creating your mask

Comment: Hi , I tried your inputs but I still face some Issue . Since svDataSvId wil be a list of unique nos so i created a list but that but it gives me error. I have updated my code                                                                                                                     raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'svDataSvId'

Comment: The error you're getting means that the DataFrame you're passing doesn't have a column named `svDataSVId` -- I'd double check for a typo and modify the code above to your own data.

That being said -- based on your later comment I'm not sure if this will be the solution you're looking for. Do you want a _single_ line that alternates in color based on those IDs? Or do you want _multiple_ lines of different color for each id?

Comment: Yes I need multiple lines of different color where each line represents a unique/each id . I need to create labels for them at top right representing what color represents which Id . Basically it should look like the picture I posted in my question .             Also I need 2 subplots:                                                                                            1. With sourceId=0                                                                                                  2. With sourceid=1